# PHP MySQL query failing in some cases?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a PHP script which receives post requests to enter clients into a database, it works most of the time but in some cases it fails if the client has special characters in his name, What makes it even more weird is if I try running the query manually in PHPMyAdmin it works fine, the php code I am using is here:

```
$mysql = new mysqli("***", "****", "****", "****");
mysqli_set_charset($mysql,"utf8mb4");

if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
$name = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST["name"]);
} else {
mysqli_close($mysql);
die("Name not set");
}

$query = sprintf ("INSERT INTO `que` (`name`, `ip`, `steamid`, `serverip`) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", $name, $clientip, $steamid, $serverip.":".$serverport);

if(!$mysql->query($query)) {
    mysqli_close($mysql);
    die("Query Failure: " . $query);
}
```

As stated, the above code works 90% of the time, but it some cases (I believe caused by special characters in the name)  it will fail.

Here are some cases of failure:

```
INSERT INTO `que` (`name`, `ip`, `steamid`, `serverip`) VALUES ('Shrimp%20á´³áµ€%20ƒ„%20s%20%20t', '****', 'STEAM_1:0:16045698', '178.32.48.195:27015')
INSERT INTO `que` (`name`, `ip`, `steamid`, `serverip`) VALUES ('â˜…â˜…%20—%20noichia%20—%20…â˜…', '****', 'STEAM_1:0:103227484', '178.32.48.195:27015')
INSERT INTO `que` (`name`, `ip`, `steamid`, `serverip`) VALUES ('â€¢%20rie%20Low%20¼rke%20¢%20Ù„', '*****', 'STEAM_1:1:60346821', '178.32.48.195:27015')
```

All the post inputs are sanitized with the following (Not that somebody can post bad things anyway since only my servers are able to post):

```
$mysql->real_escape_string
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: I also URL encode before I send the request to the PHP using the following:

```
stock void URLEncode(char[] str, int len)
{
char[] str2 = new char[len * 3 + 1];
Format(str2, len * 3 + 1, "%s", str);

char ReplaceThis[20][] =  { "%", " ", "!", "*", "'", "(", ")", ";", ":", "@", "&", "=", "+", "$", ",", "/", "?", "#", "[", "]" };
char ReplaceWith[20][] =  { "%25", "%20", "%21", "%2A", "%27", "%28", "%29", "%3B", "%3A", "%40", "%26", "%3D", "%2B", "%24", "%2C", "%2F", "%3F", "%23", "%5B", "%5D" };

for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    ReplaceString(str2, len, ReplaceThis[x], ReplaceWith[x]);
}

if (strlen(str2) > len * 3) {
    LogError("statistics encode url exceeded length (%d): %s", len * 3, str2);
}

Format(str, len, "%s", str2);

if (strlen(str) > len - 1) {
    LogError("statistics encode url exceeded length (%d): %s", len, str);
}
}
```

Comment: php string functions are not unicode aware and can/will mangle unicode data. you shouldn't be using manually-built query strings anyways. use a mysqli prepared statement with placeholders. `sprintf()` does NOT help with this. - it's still a php string function.

Comment: Prepared statements is something I was trying to avoid since I have never used them before and I have a lot of code to convert! I guess Ill bite the bullet then :P

Comment: it's the only way to go. especially since manual escaping doesn't prevent all forms of sql injection attacks.

Comment: Would this be ok to use? https://codecanyon.net/item/mysqli-easy-prepared-statements-/8714547 or is there a free alternative?

Comment: You'd be much better off going through this transition by hand. You'll gain a lot and you'll learn how prepared statements work much better. That script might work well, but if it doesn't, you'll still be going through it by hand to find the errors. Once you get the hang of it, use find and replace as you are able.

Comment: no. don't use a wrapper that hides the details... not until you KNOW what those details are about.

Comment: Okay, before I do the prepared statement, is it ok to $mysql->real_escape_string aswell?

Comment: Once you are using parameterized queries, there should be no need to use real_escape_string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comment, this is much easier if you use prepared statements. If you need to insert multiple records per view it could be faster too.

Here's how your code can be changed.

```
$mysql = new mysqli("***", "****", "****", "****");
mysqli_set_charset($mysql,"utf8mb4");

if (isset($_POST["name"])) {

    $query = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO `que` (`name`, `ip`, `steamid`, `serverip`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")
    $query->bind_param("ssss", $name, $clientip, $steamid, $serverip.":".$serverport);

    if($query->execute()) {
        print 'ok';
    }

} else {

   print 'Sorry required data not found';
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that you don't need to explicitly close the connection.

Comment: I ended up using something similar to this but I still get problems in some strange cases.

Comment: Great. Appreciate if you could mark the answer as correct so that it ma help someone else also. Alternatively, please post this comment as your own answer and accept your own answer as correct. in that case , please be so kind as to upvote for me :)

Comment: http://paste.ee/p/QBFth#T4TpyLByw7TwSWUWXHwifnHflidf9Q7R Just a note aswell, you have your if statement backwards :P